# Enviar Imagem base64 para e-mail

Tags: html, envio-de-email

Estou tentando enviar um email com uma imagem em base64. O html está indo porém a imagem não.

Um exemplo de como a mensagem é montada:

```
<p>Mensagem.</p><br><br><img style='max-height:200px; max-width: 700px; width:auto; height:auto;' src='data:image/jpeg;base64,/Base64DaMinhaImagem' alt='Não foi possível carregar a imagem'>
```

Porém não está indo a imagem e nem mesmo o 'Alt' dela está aparecendo. Se eu tento jogar o que a variável me retorna e gerar um html manual com ela está aparecendo a imagem corretamente. Estou tentando enviar para uma conta no gmail e para um outlook.

Comment: Segundo este post do SOen, não é possível utilizar pois estes clientes ignoram imagens em base64: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13051136/7762411, porém o link que direciona para a explicação não funciona mais, então não posso garantir.

Answer (score 3):

¬¬

A caixa de entrada das outras pessoas é sagrada.

Deixa eu repetir de novo, agora com ênfase. **A caixa de entrada das outras pessoas é sagrada.**.

Acho que ainda não fui claro o suficiente.

## A CAIXA DE ENTRADA DAS OUTRAS PESSOAS É SAGRADA!

---

Se você hospeda uma imagem em algum lugar e manda um email com o endereço da imagem no html, você mandou uma string. Com codificação UTF isso não dá mais de seis bytes por caractere, então mesmo uma URL longa não vai chegar a pesar um kilobyte na caixa de entrada do usuário.

Mas se você mandar uma imagem de 10 megabytes codificada como base64, é como se você tivesse mandado um anexo de 10 megabytes no email. Se toda imagem em email fosse codificada assim, não haveria armazenamento suficiente no mundo para salvar todas as caixas de entrada.

Dependendo da moral e da educação da pessoa, uma imagem codificada como base64 em um email pode ser visto como uma gafe, uma ofensa ou mesmo um ataque. Eu fui educado para achar que é caso de polícia.

Por esse motivo, o suporte de diversos clientes de email para base64 - não só GMail, mas também Yahoo! e outros - tem variado ao longo dos anos. Então, se você utilizar essa técnica, os seus resultados vão variar. Você nunca vai ter certeza se vai dar certo, e quando der, não vai ter certeza se continuará funcionando no dia seguinte. Para clientes online, pode ser que uma imagem mostrada hoje já não apareça mais daqui a alguns meses.

Portanto, se quiser continuar mandando email automático com imagem, hospede suas imagens em algum lugar. Além de ser melhor para o usuário é mais tranquilo para você dar manutenção.